# HTML inside of jQuery doesn't work for me?

Tags: jquery

Simple example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('body').css({'background-color': '#dddddd', 'font-size': '12pt'});
 $('table tr:odd').addClass('rowShaded');
 $('<p> Oh my learning jQuery is so fun </p>').addClass('myP');
 $('#myButton').click(function() {
  alert($(this).attr("value")); //should display the name of the button
     $('#myTestTable').toggle();
    });


});
```

**`$('<p> Oh my learning jQuery is so fun </p>').addClass('myP');`**

Everything is working fine except that line.  Shouldn't it actually show a new paragraph on my page with that text?  I dont see it, all it shows is a table in my html and button that I can toggle.  I thought you can add HTML elements and jQuery places it in the html file ?  My CSS is simple for that element:

```
.myP{
font-family:verdana;
color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you have to tell jQuery where it should be shown in your page, using e.g. [`appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/).

Example:

```
('<p> Oh my learning jQuery is so fun </p>')
.addClass('myP')
.appendTo('#mydiv');
```

appends the HTML to the element with ID `mydiv` (meaning the `p` element is now the last child of `#mydiv`).

Comment: I actually ended up using insertAfter() cool thanks, ill accept in 11 minutes

Answer (score 1):

In that line you created a new HTML element and added a class to it. You then have to add it to the DOM.

```
$('body').append($('<p> Oh my learning jQuery is so fun </p>').addClass('myP'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('***').append('<p> Oh my learning jQuery is so fun </p>').addClass('myP');
```

replace *** with appropriate selecotr

Comment: This wouldn't work properly. It would not add the class to the new `<p>`, but rather to the container to which it is being appended.

Comment: @patrick - very true good comment definately.  You want to .addClass to the actual p and not the original selector @dejavu

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware that's not how jQuery selectors work; you can get all paras with $('p'), or paras with a given id or class...  Check out http://www.pamaya.com/jquery-selectors-and-attribute-selectors-reference-and-examples/ for examples of how to reference stuff.

Comment: No, you can generate new HTML this way.

Comment: No downvote but you can certainly add HTML elements right from jQuery.

Comment: Oh well, it's good to learn stuff!  Time for me to have a play with some jQuery methinks :D

Comment: Yep, I take it all back, jQuery is smart enough to parse $('<p>...</p>') as some new HTML, and not some incomprehensible element to select.  Which makes jQuery much smarter than me, apparently!